# Prevent SIGTERM & SIGKILL when using shutdown on macos

Tags: macos, shutdown

Is there any way to prevent sending the sigterm & sigkill when using shutdown?
I have a script which puts my mac to sleep, which contains shutdown -s to put my mac to sleep. Only I would like it not to send the sigkill to all my open terminals. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `shutdown -s` you can use one of

```
pmset sleepnow
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to sleep'
```